# Remove first word from the sentence and return remaining string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, function

Write a function that is given a phrase and returns the phrase we get if we take
out the first word from the input phrase.
For example, given ‘the quick brown fox’, your function should return ‘quick brown fox’
This is my code:

```
def whatistheremainder(v):
    remainderforone = v.split(' ', 1)
    outcome = remainderforone[1:]
    return outcome
```

Instead of getting a sensible output like:
'quick brown fox'
I am getting something like this:

```
['quick brown fox']
```

Please help

Comment: the `.split()` function splits the string into a list, to convert it back to a string you can use `" ".join(outcome)` function

Comment: I don't think what you mentioned is what you would be getting. Currently I think you are getting list of words as: `['quick', 'brown', 'fox']`. To convert this into string, you need to use `str.join` as: `' '.join(['quick', 'brown', 'fox'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted to get

```
def whatistheremainder(v):
    remainderforone = v.split(' ', 1)
    outcome = remainderforone[1:][0]
    return outcome
print(whatistheremainder('the quick brown fox'))
```

Output

```
quick brown fox
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. One question: Why isn't it working with one word e.g Alaska

Answer (score 1):

`[1:]` takes a *slice* from the list, which is itself a list:

```
>>> remainderforone
['the', 'quick brown fox']
>>> remainderforone[1:]
['quick brown fox']
```

Here the slice notation `[1:]` says to slice everything from index 1 (the second item) to the end of the list. There are only two items in the list, so you get a list of size one because the first item is skipped over.

To fix just extract a single element of the list. We know that the list should contain 2 elements, so you want the second item so just use index 1:

```
>>> remainderforone[1]
'quick brown fox'
```

As a more general solution you might want to consider using [`str.partition()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=partition#str.partition):

```
for s in ['the quick brown fox', 'hi there', 'single', '', 'abc\tefg']:
    first, sep, rest = s.partition(' ')
    first, sep, rest

('the', ' ', 'quick brown fox')
('hi', ' ', 'there')
('single', '', '')
('', '', '')
('abc\tefg', '', '')
```

Depending on how you want to handle those cases where no partitioning occurred you could just return `rest`, or possibly `first`:

```
def whatistheremainder(v):
    first, sep, rest = v.partition(' ')
    return rest

for s in ['the quick brown fox', 'hi there', 'single', '', 'abc\tefg']:
    whatistheremainder(s)

'quick brown fox'
'there'
''
''
''
```

Or you could argue that the original string should be returned if no partitioning occurred because there was no first word to remove. You can use the fact that `sep` will be an empty string if no partitioning occurred:

```
def whatistheremainder(v):
    first, sep, rest = v.partition(' ')
    return rest if sep else first

for s in ['the quick brown fox', 'hi there', 'single', '', 'abc\tefg']:
    whatistheremainder(s)

'quick brown fox'
'there'
'single'
''
'abc\tefg'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic can be further simplified in one line by setting `maxsplit` param as `1` for [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function as:

```
>>> my_string = 'the quick brown fox'

>>> my_string.split(' ', 1)[1]
'quick brown fox'
```

This will raise `IndexError` if your string is with one or no word.

Another alternative **using *string slicing* with `list.index(...)`** as:

```
>>> my_string[my_string.index(' ')+1:]
'quick brown fox'
```

Similar to earlier solution, this one will also not work for one or no word string and will raise `ValueError` exception.

**To handle strings with one or no word**, you can utilise the first solution using `maxsplit` param, but access it as list using *list slicing* instead of index and join it back:

```
>>> ''.join(my_string.split(' ', 1)[1:])
'quick brown fox'
```

---

Issue with your code is that your need to join the list of strings you are sending back using `' '.join(outcome)`. Hence, your function will become:

```
def whatistheremainder(v):
    remainderforone = v.split(' ', 1)
    outcome = remainderforone[1:]
    return ' '.join(outcome)
```

Sample run:

```
>>> whatistheremainder('the quick brown fox')
'quick brown fox'
```

You above logic to split the string into words and joining it back skipping first word can also be converted into one line as:

```
>>> ' '.join(my_string.split()[1:])
'quick brown fox'
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Will it work for one word. Please tell me which code to use if I want it to work with one word eg. Alaska or Kingdom

Comment: @revisionweb you can go ahead with the version i highlighted with "To handle strings with one or no word"

Comment: Are you sure you are using this one? `''.join('Hello'.split(' ', 1)[1:])` Here I am passing `'Hello'` as single word string. This code will return you empty string

Comment: Is it possible to return hello back not empty

Comment: you can use this in that case `my_string.split(' ', 1)[1] if ' ' in my_string else my_string`. where `my_string` is your variable

Answer (score 0):

```
 def whatistheremainder(v):
    remainderforone = v.split(' ', 1)
    outcome=v if len(remainderforone)== 1 else ''.join(remainderforone[1:])
    return outcome
```

this line 'outcome=v if len(remainderforone)== 1 else ''.join(remainderforone[1:])' check if the length of the list contains all the words if the length is equal to 1 its mean there is only one word so the outcome will equal to v (the word entered) else mean there is more then one word the outcome will equal to the entered string without the first word

Answer (score -1):

```
 def whatistheremainder(v):
    remainderforone = v.split(' ', 1)
    outcome = ''.join(remainderforone[1:])
    return outcome
```

Comment: Hi new user, please add commentary into your answer as to why this should be used. including any documentation that may be helpful. This will help future readers understand if they should use it for their problem.

Comment: The code is superb. Just wondering what I could do for one word like 'alaska'

Comment: you can add a simple if and else statement to check the length of this list splited  '    outcome=v if len(remainderforone)== 1 else ''.join(remainderforone[1:])
'